# Audit reports not appearing on windows command prompt

Tags: protractor, accessibility

This may sound novice but am kind of stuck hence dared to ask.

I am trying to get accessibility audit report using Protractor accessibility plugin.

I'm using demo script:

```js
describe("TC_001",function(){

 it("using demo site", function(){
  browser.get("http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo");
  expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
 });
 
});
```

and this is conf.js

```js
exports.config = {
  framework : 'jasmine2',
  seleniumServerJar : './node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar',
  seleniumPort : '4444',
  /*capabilities : {
   browserName : 'firefox'
  },*/
  specs :['./TC_001.js'],
  jasmineNodeopts:{
   defaultTimeoutInterval:500000
  },
  plugins:[{
   chromeA11DevTools:{
    treatWarningsAsFailures:true
    },
   package:'protractor-accessibility-plugin'
   //path:'node_modules/protractor/plugins/accessibility'
  }],
  onPrepare: function(){
   var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
   jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: true,
    savePath: './testresults',
    filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
   }));
  }
   
};
```

i could run the script fine, using 'protractor conf.js' however no audit report appears in command prompt.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

EDIT

As per suggestion, i've updated config file to report result in JSON format.

```js
var JSONReporter = require('jasmine-json-test-reporter');
exports.config = {
  
  seleniumServerJar : './node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar',
  seleniumPort : '4444',
  /*capabilities : {
   browserName : 'firefox'
  },*/
  
  
  specs :['./TC_001.js'],
  jasmineNodeopts:{
   defaultTimeoutInterval:500000
  },
  
  
  
  plugins:[{
   chromeA11DevTools:{
    treatWarningsAsFailures:true
    },
   //package:'protractor-accessibility-plugin'
   path:'node_modules/protractor/plugins/accessibility'
  }],
  
  
  framework : 'jasmine2',
  onPrepare: function(){
   /*var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
   jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: true,
    savePath: './testresults',
    filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
   }));*/
   var JSONReporter = require('jasmine-json-test-reporter');
   jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new JSONReporter({
    file:'jamine-test-results.json',
    beautify: true,
    indentationLevel:4
   }));
   
  }
   
};
```

This does generate JSON file but result has no trace of accessibility audit.

```js
{
    "suite1": {
        "id": "suite1",
        "description": "TC_001",
        "fullName": "TC_001",
        "failedExpectations": [],
        "status": "finished",
        "specs": [
            {
                "id": "spec0",
                "description": "using demo site",
                "fullName": "TC_001 using demo site",
                "failedExpectations": [],
                "passedExpectations": [
                    {
                        "matcherName": "toEqual",
                        "message": "Passed.",
                        "stack": "",
                        "passed": true
                    }
                ],
                "pendingReason": "",
                "status": "passed"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it working and it was because of a typo. I was using 'chromeA11DevTools' rather than 'chromeA11YDevTools'.

Thank you for all those who helped.

For those who are starting - this video is great - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2Pt6Xx94Bc&index=2&list=PLcqd8qPb2GfPdO-ptcsYL7NVgBbMoKaNu

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no support for accessibility plugin with jasmine reporters, instead you could use JSON format to generate reports with the help of: `resultJsonOutputFile`, for more details you could checkout the answer from the author of protractor herself ;) [Report accessibility plugin results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913799/report-accessibility-plugin-results)

```
 exports.config = {

    seleniumServerJar : './node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar',
    seleniumPort : '4444',
    /*capabilities : {
        browserName : 'firefox'
    },*/


    specs :['./TC_001.js'],
    jasmineNodeopts:{
        defaultTimeoutInterval:500000
    },



    plugins:[{
        chromeA11DevTools:{
            treatWarningsAsFailures:true
            },
        //package:'protractor-accessibility-plugin'
        path:'node_modules/protractor/plugins/accessibility'
    }],


    framework : 'jasmine2',
    resultJsonOutputFile : './Report.json',

    onPrepare: function(){
        /*var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            consolidateAll: true,
            savePath: './testresults',
            filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
        }));*/

    }

  };
```

It will create `Report.json` in your current directoy!

Comment: thanks @igniteram1 ! I will try that and mark your reply as answer if it works. thanks again!

Comment: sure please try and let me know!

Comment: I had look at other question. For me the issue is the result does not appear even in terminal :( 

This is what appears for me: 

D:\Workspace\accessibilityProject>protractor conf.js
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.106.1:4444/wd/hub
Started
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 4.795 seconds
Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 passed

Comment: btw, i tried the other solution as well. I've the JSON file generated but it does not list down any accessibility audit.

Comment: Why are you using a separate ```jasmine-json-test-reporter``` module, protractor has inbuilt capability for that. I have updated my answer with your config file. Please use that and let me know!

Comment: thanks again!, i've tried the solution you've suggested; i.e. using protractor inbuilt reporter. However still the problem persists; no audit report generated :(